# Как сверстать многоуровневое меню?

Tags: javascript, css

Как сверстать такое многоуровневое меню?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если без бокового блока с картинкой, то все понятно. При наведении на элемент списка показываем дочерний список. Как сверстать меню с боковым блоком, который индивидуален для каждого элемента списка?

Comment: [только первый пункт выпадает по клику](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PowrrqK?editors=0100) а на js при mouseout снять checkbox

Comment: а как оно появляется? сразу с выбранным первым пунктом(запеченные острые суши) и открытым блоком с картинкой? Или он изначально пустой? Или сперва появляется вложенный список и при наведении на пункт выдвигается блок с картинкой?

Answer (score 7):

Как-то чересчур сложно получилось.

```js
var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__item');
var currentItemName;
var currentSubmenu;
var currentSubmenuItems;
var currentSubmenuInfoInner;

menuItems.forEach(menuItem => {
  menuItem.onmouseenter = () => {
    currentItemName = menuItem.firstElementChild;
    currentSubmenu = currentItemName.nextElementSibling;
    currentSubmenuItems = currentSubmenu.querySelectorAll('.submenu__list__item');
    currentSubmenuInfoInner = currentSubmenu.querySelector('.submenu__info').firstElementChild;

    var isAnySelected = [...currentSubmenuItems].find(csi => csi.classList.contains('submenu__list__item_selected'));
    if (!isAnySelected) {
      currentSubmenuItems[0].classList.add('submenu__list__item_selected');
      currentSubmenuInfoInner.style.backgroundColor = currentSubmenuItems[0].dataset.color;
    }

    currentSubmenuItems.forEach(currentSubmenuItem => {
      currentSubmenuItem.onmouseenter = () => {
        currentSubmenuItems.forEach(csi => csi.classList.remove('submenu__list__item_selected'));

        currentSubmenuItem.classList.add('submenu__list__item_selected');
        currentSubmenuInfoInner.style.backgroundColor = currentSubmenuItem.dataset.color;
      };
    });

    currentItemName.classList.add('menu__item__name_selected');
    currentSubmenu.classList.add('submenu_shown');

    currentSubmenuBox = currentSubmenu.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (currentSubmenuBox.right > innerWidth) {
      currentSubmenu.style.left = `${innerWidth - currentSubmenuBox.left}px`;
    }
  };

  menuItem.onmouseleave = () => {
    currentItemName.classList.remove('menu__item__name_selected');
    currentSubmenu.classList.remove('submenu_shown');
  };
});
```

```css
:root {
  --menu-height: 20vh;
  --submenu-height: 80vh;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  height: var(--menu-height);
  display: flex;
  background-color: #633e8e;
  color: white;
}

.menu__item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-shadow: -0.4px 0 0 white;
}

.menu__item__name {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu__item__name_selected {
  background-color: #4b2975;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: var(--submenu-height);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #4b2975;
  transition: transform 1s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.submenu_shown {
  transform: translateY(calc(100% + var(--menu-height)));
}

.submenu__list {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.submenu__list__item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.submenu__list__item_selected {
  background-color: #906abd;
}

.submenu__info {
  flex-grow: 3;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #906abd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.submenu__info__inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item">
    <div class="menu__item__name">Суши</div>

    <div class="submenu">
      <ul class="submenu__list">
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="tomato">Запеченные острые суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="coral">Запеченные суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="lightblue">Классические суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="lightgreen">Острые суши</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="submenu__info">
        <div class="submenu__info__inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="menu__item">
    <div class="menu__item__name">Суши</div>

    <div class="submenu">
      <ul class="submenu__list">
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="tomato">Запеченные острые суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="coral">Запеченные суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="lightblue">Классические суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="lightgreen">Острые суши</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="submenu__info">
        <div class="submenu__info__inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="menu__item">
    <div class="menu__item__name">Суши</div>

    <div class="submenu">
      <ul class="submenu__list">
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="tomato">Запеченные острые суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="coral">Запеченные суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="lightblue">Классические суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="lightgreen">Острые суши</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="submenu__info">
        <div class="submenu__info__inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="menu__item">
    <div class="menu__item__name">Суши</div>

    <div class="submenu">
      <ul class="submenu__list">
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="tomato">Запеченные острые суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="coral">Запеченные суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="lightblue">Классические суши</li>
        <li class="submenu__list__item" data-color="lightgreen">Острые суши</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="submenu__info">
        <div class="submenu__info__inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: вообще круто получилось -

Comment: @Sevastopol' Убрал гриды. Без флексов - уже какой-то фетиш.

Answer (score 6):

На CSS

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 50px;
  background: #633e8e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  color: inherit;
}

.nav>.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav>.item.drop::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-top: 6px solid #a892c1;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.nav>.item:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #7d5ba7;
}

.nav>.item:hover {
  background: #4b2975;
}

.nav>.item>.droped {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #4b2975;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.nav>.item:hover .droped {
  display: block;
}

.nav>.item .droped>.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav>.item .droped>.item.drop {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.nav>.item .droped>.item:hover {
  background: #906abd;
}

.nav>.item .droped>.item>.droped {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  min-height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: #906abd;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.nav>.item .droped>.item>.droped img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 150px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.nav>.item .droped>.item:hover .droped {
  display: flex;
}

.nav>.item .droped>.item:first-child>.droped {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="item drop">
    <div class="text">Суши</div>
    <div class="droped">
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Запеченные острые суши</div>
        <div class="droped">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GkVXrea.png"><br>
          <a href="#">Суши с доставкой - полезное, вкусное и практичное решение вопроса питая в</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Запеченные суши</div>
        <div class="droped"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Классические суши</div>
        <div class="droped"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Острые суши</div>
        <div class="droped"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item drop">
    <div class="text">Роллы</div>
    <div class="droped">
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Запеченные острые суши</div>
        <div class="droped">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GkVXrea.png"><br>
          <a href="#">Суши с доставкой - полезное, вкусное и практичное решение вопроса питая в</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Запеченные суши</div>
        <div class="droped"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Классические суши</div>
        <div class="droped"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Острые суши</div>
        <div class="droped"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item drop">
    <div class="text">Наборы</div>
    <div class="droped">
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Запеченные острые суши</div>
        <div class="droped">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GkVXrea.png"><br>
          <a href="#">Суши с доставкой - полезное, вкусное и практичное решение вопроса питая в</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Запеченные суши</div>
        <div class="droped"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Классические суши</div>
        <div class="droped"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item drop">
        <div class="text">Острые суши</div>
        <div class="droped"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```